# When i call the ajax in node.js as a return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

my node.js code

index.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var client = mysql.createConnection({
    user : 'root',
    password : '1234',
    database : 'company'
});
exports.index = function(req, res) {
fs.readFile('views/index.html','utf-8',function(error,data){
    client.query('select * from spa',function(error,result){
        if(error){
            console.log('error:'+error);
        }else{
            res.send(ejs.render(data,{
                title:'Express',
                result:result
            }));
        }//end else
    });//end query
});//end fs
};
```

my index.html code

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function listView() {
        $('#output').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url : '/',
            type : 'GET',
            success : function(result) {
                alert('success');
                alert(typeof (result));
                $(result).each(function(index, item) {
                    var output = '';
                    output += '<tr>';
                    output += '<td>' + item.file_no + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + item.file_name + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + item.file_content + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + item.file_model + '</td>';
                    output += '</tr>';
                    $('#output').append(output);
                });//end each
            }//end success
        });//end ajax
    }//end listView();
   });//end document
 </script>

<table id="output"></table>
```

when i run the code until success is well performed. alert('success') ->worked!

alert(typeof(result))->string >worked! but Table of all the data that's it undefined.

i don't know situation.. plz help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said `typeof (result)` is `string`, hopefully `JSON`. But if want to iterate over it, then you have to parse as `javascript` array

```
var resultArray = JSON.parse(result);
```

Then iterate over an array

```
$.each(resultArray, function(index, item) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you  just want to iterate through the result object, instead of this:

```
$(result).each(function(index, item) {
```

I think you probably want:

```
$.each(result, function(index, item) {
```

---

If that still doesn't get you where you want, then add a

```
console.log(result);
```

to examine exactly what the result of the ajax call is and make sure you have exactly the data you expected and that you're iterating the right part of it.

Comment: And, if you'd done a `console.log(result)` like I suggested you would have seen that it was a string, not a javascript object.  This is basic and simple debugging.  It's worth learning how to look into these things yourself.